# Inicio de la serie Highcharts tipo bar en un punto específico

Tags: highcharts

Como puedo crear series de tipo bar que no empizen por 0 sino que empizen desde un valor hasta otro.

Por ejemplo la segunda serie quiero que empieze por 50000

https://jsfiddle.net/jmsalai/kpw9j8vs/

En el ejemplo he utilizado una series como margen con plotOptions stacking 'normal'.

Se puede hacer sin utilizar una serie como margen ?

Si se tiene que utilizar una serie como margen, esta se puede ocultar el texto y tooltip de la serie ?